# Erasing line feature (erase feature) from polygon feature in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, line, erase

How can I erase a "line feature" (erase feature) from a "polygone feature" (input) in ArcGIS 10?

With the tool "erase" I can only use an other "polygon feature" as erase feature for a polygon (input).But I can not use an "line feature" as erase feature for a polygon.

I there an other tool in ArcGIS or an other way to solve this problem?

Comment: ? And what is the expected result? Two polygons separated by the line?

Comment: It should be one polygone with a gap in shape of the line.
So the line should have some width but then it is not a line anymore but a polygon?
So how can a create a polygon of defined width from line feature? If I could create such polygon feature I could use the "erase" Tool to create the gaps.

Comment: The Buffer Tool will create a Polygon from a Line, at a specified width.

Comment: A line feature has no area. You can either split a polygon with a line feature, or, as you have now suggested, buffer the line feature by a certain width to create a new polygon, and then erase it from your original polygon feature.

Comment: or you convert your polygon to line and erase the line.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @HDunn:

> A line feature has no area. You can either split a polygon with a line
>   feature, or, as you have now suggested, buffer the line feature by a
>   certain width to create a new polygon, and then erase it from your
>   original polygon feature.